# Syncing photos from Mac with iPad

Tags: mac, ipad, photos

My Mac and my iPad are synced so I can get messages and take pictures with both. When I take a picture with my Mac it doesn't show up on my iPad, vice versa.

How can I get Mac photos to my iPad?

If someone can answer this I will be very thankful!

Answer (score -1):

You can enable iCloud Photos which will sync photos between all devices as long as you use the same AppleID on all of them. Apple has extensive documentation on this, see https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204264 for a first introduction.

PS: There is a lot of useful stuff on https://support.apple.com/ which should help in getting started with using Apple devices.